# Как настроить маршрутизацию?

Tags: php, yii, mvc

Здравствуйте.

Как можно сделать чтобы я по ссылке

```
domain.com/o-kompanii
```

попадал на

```
domain.com/index.php?r=page/default/index&alias=o-kompanii
```

а по ссылке

```
domain.com/admin
```

попадал на

```
domain.com/index.php?r=admin
```

Ведь если написать так  `'/<alias>' => 'page/default/index/'` - я не смогу попасть на контролер `admin`, так как оно будет искать page с `alias=admin`.

Как решить такую проблему?

Comment: Если используете `yii1`, то, логично, не ставить в метках [tag:yii2]. На будущее...

Answer (score 0):

Можно прописать маршрут для domain.com/o-kompanii, а в контроллере вызывать

```
header("domain.com/index.php?r=page/default/index&alias=o-kompanii");
```

Ну и с domain.com/admin - аналогично.

Но лучше всего так не делать, ничего никуда не перенаправлять, сделать нормальный контроллер для каждого человекопонятного URL, а повторяющийся код (из-за которого, видимо возникло желание все делать в index.php, передавая ему параметры), вынести в отдельный метод или функцию

Answer (score 0):

Роутер в yii перестает искать шаблон, как только находит первый подходящий. В итоге у вас фреймворк находит первым `'/<alias>'`, для `domain.com/admin` и дальше уже не пытается найти другой вариант. Исходя из этого, вначале указываете предопределенные значения, затем по шаблонам:

```
'/admin'=>'admin/index'

'/<alias>' => 'page/default/index/'
```